# Overfull hbox when including characters after a number in siunitx table columns

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to mark certain entries in a siunitx table column with either +, *, or ?, but when I do so, I get overfull hbox warnings. I've tried to use `table-space-text-post` to give more space, but it doesn't seem to have an effect on the overfull hbox situation. (It's also deprecated, but I'm unsure how to set `table-format` to achieve the same effect.)

The table is a bit squished to fit in a single column, but the default tabcolsep still causes overfull hboxes in table entries.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2em}
    \newcolumntype{d}{S[input-signs=,input-symbols=+,table-format=3.1,table-space-text-post={$+$}]}

    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rdddddddd@{}}
        \toprule
        Foo & {\% $+$ve} & {\% $-$ve} & {\% $+$ve} & {\% $-$ve} & {\% $+$ve} & {\% $-$ve} & {\% $+$ve} & {\% $-$ve} \\ \midrule
         3 & 100.0+ &   0.0  &  13.3* &   4.4  & 100.0+ &   0.0  &   6.7? &   2.2  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Overfull hboxes correspond to `+` characters in the table:

```
Overfull \hbox (6.6112pt too wide) detected at line 15
 

Overfull \hbox (6.6112pt too wide) detected at line 15
```

Visually, things look okay, but I'd like to know how to do set the column width correctly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is too wide that can be fit in one column. See if prescribing table width and reformulating column headers into two lines as done in the following MWWE (minimal Working Example) is acceptable to you. In it distances between columns is left to LaTeX to determine:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % considered is version 3
\usepackage{booktabs}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\sisetup{input-signs=,
         input-symbols=+,
         table-format=3.1{$+$}
         }
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \centering
%    \small
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r @{\quad} *{8}{S} }
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{8}{c}{share in \%}    \\
    \cmidrule{2-9}
Foo & {$+$ve} & {$-$ve} & {$+$ve} & {$-$ve} & {$+$ve} & {$-$ve} & {$+$ve} & {$-$ve} \\ 
    \midrule
3   & 100.0+     &  0.0       & 13.3*      &   4.4      & 100.0+     & 0.0        & 6.7?       & 2.2        \\
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped a good bit, as did upgrading to a newer siunitx -- turns out the version in debian stable/testing texlive is from 2020.

Comment: @Natasha, new `siunitx` version was published in this year summer :-)

Comment: I have the latest and greatest now, and it is quite great!